# Ввод текста на форме Eclipse

Tags: java

Здрасте, как отобразить текстовое поле на форме? Вот к примеру у меня вот так:

```
    JFrame f = new JFrame("asd");
        JPanel p = new JPanel();

        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(400, 400);
        f.setVisible(true);

        p.setSize(100,100);
        p.setVisible(true);

/*может я что то не то делаю, но все эти вариаты не работают*/
        f.getContentPane().add(p);
        //f.add(p);
        //f.setContentPane(p);
```

Comment: ну так у вас нету здесь ни одного элемента для ввода текста. фрейм - это окно, панель - контейнер элементов... установите `p` цвет и сами все увидите

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://javaswing.wordpress.com/2009/07/10/use-jframe/ Простой пример. А там уже сами.